# Laradock Nginx throws 413 error entity too large even if size = 20M and my file is 1.5MB

Tags: laravel, nginx, laradock

I am deploying a Laravel app by using Laradock.

When testing the upload part with two different 1.5MB dummy files (.docx and .pdf), I get the following error:

I already have checked the Nginx's `nginx.conf` file and it does have that setting to 20MB:

```
...
http {
  server_tokens off;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 15;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  client_max_body_size 20M;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /dev/stdout;
  error_log /dev/stderr;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
...
```

I have reloaded the configurations:

```
$ sudo docker exec myapp_nginx_99 nginx -t
$ sudo docker exec myapp_nginx_99 nginx -s reload
```

But the error is still thrown:

> 413 Request Entity Too Large

Inside a `php.ini` file I have the following:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
;upload_tmp_dir =

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

I can see the maximum is 2MB, but I have tried with a 1.1MB PDF file and I still get the error.

Also, I have found out a `laravel.ini` right at the `php-fpm` directory and this is the original configuration:

```
date.timezone=UTC
display_errors=Off
log_errors=On

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 256M
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 20M
; Sets max size of post data allowed.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 20M
max_execution_time=600
default_socket_timeout=3600
request_terminate_timeout=600
```

However, if I try with a 836KB file, the upload is successful. Looks like the Max file upload is 1MB, but I can't find it anywhere ...

Given that I'm already using other applications, I am using a Nginx-proxy from [Evert Ramos](https://github.com/evertramos/docker-compose-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion) to resolve for each domain. Looks like the problem lies here.

If I execute `$ nginx -T` on this proxy container, I don't see the `client_max_body_size`

What else am I missing to fix this?

Comment: have you restarted php-fpm after change?

Comment: @ThaiNguyenHung Thank you for the idea! Right at the Evert Ramos Nginx proxy container, I uncommented the custom config value of `client_max_body_size` at the `.env`file. Then I  re-executed the installation script, so that the .env changes would take effect and that did the trick. Before that I'd tried `docker-compose restart` and `docker-compose up -d` which hadn't worked.